# Programmatically accessing an iframe that uses a data URI as a source

Tags: javascript, iframe, webkit

I'm creating an iframe programmatically using the "data" URI:

```
<iframe id="myFrame" src='data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><h1>Hello.</h1></body></html>'></iframe>​
```

This frame loads fine, but it seems that working with the iframe programmatically hits cross-domain security checks.

```
var iframeDoc = document.getElementById('myFrame').contentWindow.document;
$(iframeDoc.body).find('h1').text('Changed');
```

Throws an error in Chrome and Safari:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   data:text/html;charset=utf-8,... from frame with URL http://... The
>   frame requesting access has a protocol of 'http', the frame being
>   accessed has a protocol of ''. Protocols must match.

Here's a fiddle showing the security error: http://jsfiddle.net/bhGcw/4/

Firefox and Opera do not throw this exception and allow the iframe contents to be changed. Seems like Webkit sees a blank protocol for data URIs, and sees this as a cross-domain violation.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: is this it? http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82402 it's for chromium, not chrome, but maybe it has same issue. also i found some security issue for phishing, which chrome tries to prevent, it may be it too

Comment: Yep, that definitely looks related. Was hoping that there was a workaround, but appears that there isn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that Webkit does a simple string comparison in their [domain checking code](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=external/WebKit_trimmed.git;a=blob_plain;f=Source/WebCore/page/DOMWindow.cpp):

```
String DOMWindow::crossDomainAccessErrorMessage(DOMWindow* activeWindow)
{
    ...

    SecurityOrigin* activeOrigin = activeWindow->document()->securityOrigin();
    SecurityOrigin* targetOrigin = document()->securityOrigin();
    if (targetOrigin->protocol() != activeOrigin->protocol())
        return message + " The frame requesting access has a protocol of '" + activeOrigin->protocol() + "', the frame being accessed has a protocol of '" + targetOrigin->protocol() + "'. Protocols must match.\n";

    ...
}
```

It looks like Chromium is being more strict than the HTML5 spec, at least according the following bug reports:

- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17352
- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58999

Chromium devs don't seem to be in favor of relaxing this rule. Bummer.

Comment: Interesting comment, but unfortunately it does not answer the question

Answer (score 9):

It's a bit late, how about instead of using a data URL, you use the HTML5 attribute srcdoc.

```
<iframe id="iframe" srcdoc='<html><body><h1>Hello!</h1></body></html>'></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $($("iframe")[0].contentWindow.document).find("h1").text("Modified from the parent window!");
    });
</script>
```

There's an example at http://jsfiddle.net/ff3bF/

Comment: That's a little disappointing. Someone's authored a polyfill (https://github.com/jugglinmike/srcdoc-polyfill)

Answer (score 6):

The answer put forward by @jamie works well for loading HTML into an iframe and allowing subsequent programatic interaction with the content document.

XHTML is not so easy.

The `srcdoc` attribute appears to be limited to HTML, not XHTML.

A work around is to use a `Blob` URL which allows the `content-type` to be specified.

```
var documentSource = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\n<head>...';
var blob = new Blob([documentSource], { type: "application/xhtml+xml" });
iframe.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

This technique works for at least Chrome, Firefox and Safari.